# FunctionInvocationException when blob file not found

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am creating a function that reads a custom file in our storage. The function.json is similar to this one:

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "resource/{code}",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "item",
      "path": "data/20171003/{code}.json",
      "connection": "blog_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

In postman, if I type an existing file, it will correctly invoke the function. If the file does not exists, on the other hand, the azure runtime will throw an error:

> {
>       "id": "4ef77dcd-f8ed-4327-9447-969da6b328a9",
>       "requestId": "0a9874dd-6a7b-4717-ae9f-c3c1e3bb16c8",
>       "statusCode": 500,
>       "errorCode": 0,
>       "message": "Exception while executing function: Functions.func_ativos -> Valor não pode ser nulo.\r\nNome do
>   parâmetro: stream",
>       "errorDetails": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception
>   while executing function: Functions.func_ativos --->
>   System.ArgumentNullException : Valor não pode ser nulo.\r\nNome do
>   parâmetro: stream\r\n   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream
>   stream,Encoding encoding,Boolean
>   detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks,Int32 bufferSize,Boolean
>   leaveOpen)\r\n   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream)\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Binding.FunctionBinding.ConvertStreamToValue(Stream
>   stream,DataType dataType,Object& converted)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Binding.FunctionBinding.BindStreamAsync(BindingContext
>   context,FileAccess access)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Binding.ExtensionBinding.BindAsync(BindingContext
>   context)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.NodeFunctionInvoker.ProcessInputBindingsAsync(Binder
>   binder,Dictionary`2 executionContext,Dictionary`2 bindingData)\r\n
>   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.NodeFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[]
>   parameters,FunctionInvocationContext context)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[]
>   parameters)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnType](TReflected
>   instance,Object[] arguments)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object[]
>   arguments)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker
>   invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource
>   timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource
>   functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan
>   timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance
>   instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,TraceWriter
>   traceWriter,ILogger logger,CancellationTokenSource
>   functionCancellationTokenSource)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n
>   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
>   \r\n   End of inner exception\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n
>   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance
>   functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ExceptionDispatchInfoDelayedException.Throw()\r\n
>   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.CallAsync(??)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost.CallAsync(String
>   method,Dictionary`2 arguments,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n
>   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostManager.HandleRequestAsync(FunctionDescriptor
>   function,HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request,FunctionDescriptor function,CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0(??)\r\n
>   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.HttpRequestManager.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request,Func`3 processRequestHandler,CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.SystemTraceHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.WebScriptHostHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
>   System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)" }

I want to send a 404 status code when the file is not found, not an ugly stack like that (and error 500). What is the best approach I should follow?

== update

Please note that *FunctionInvocationException* happens **before** my function is called. It seems an error in *Azure Functions Runtime* that I cannot know if is a bug or expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also could catch the exception in the Azure function App.  In your case you could  catch the exception and return the http status code `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`

```
 public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            try
            {
                //Todo ：Add your own logic
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

**Edit:**

As you mentioned that it happens before the function is called, it seems that returned by Azure function integrated SDK. It perhaps is by designed. We also could give our idea to [azure function team](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions).

If we want to control the logic, my work around is that we could remove the input blob and implement the customized logic ourselves. We could get the sample code from the [Microsoft Azure Storage SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node).

[image]

Comment: I am using javascript functions but I think the problem is the same: the error happens before my function is called (and it is never called in this case). I cannot catch the exception by normal ways, I think.

Comment: I was expecting to receive the binding empty if the file does not exists, not an error in the azure functions runtime. I can't even know if this is a bug or expected.

Comment: I have updated the answer, we could remove the input binding and use [SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) to do that.

Comment: The solutions does not suits the problem, but it seems impossible to do what I want at this moment. The workaround will be quite expensive when compared to what I was trying to do.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the runtime since a DocumentDB binding returns empty variable when the result is not found. The behavior is not consistent.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer and if it changes somewhere in the future I update the question.